# Storing object in Redis with a lot of changes for (nodeJS)

Tags: node.js, performance, redis

I'm having a hard time to understand how i can have a detached state from my nodejs servers.

If want to run multiple nodejs instances that share the same state, i use Redis for that but i have a lot of objects that i need to store & get very frequently (it could be a lot of set/get in like 10 milisecond on a same given object for example).

Redis store things in string, so i have to json encode/decode it everytime and i don't think it's fast or appropriate for objects that will change every few MS..

I i had only one nodejs instance i could just store my object in a var and it would be fast enough but i can't in this case so should i still continue to use redis or another alternative maybe ?

Or should i decompose all of my objects keys and store it separatly in redis ? that would be overkill ?

I'm talking about thousand of objects (it's for an online multiplayer game)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's works for you, but you can create one server for DB that will handle all the requests, and all other servers will call him (get/insert) with queue from Redis.

Comment: i could indeed, but then i don't even have to use redis if i have one master server since  i only need my objects to be in the memory i can store them on the master server in variables directly but idk if it's the best option

Comment: The use for redis is to send messages between servers and maybe to handle queues. in your situation you can store the data in the client side (if it's temporary)